# Как в Visual Studio указать папку в которой программа должна искать dll?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, dll

Программа работает если dll файлы лежат в одной папке с exe.
Как сделать так чтобы при запуске программа искала dll файлы в папке которая находится в одном каталоге с exe?

[image: **введите сюда описание изображения**]

Comment: просто изменить переменную PATH, я в таких случаях делаю bat-файл, который временно модифицирует PATH и запускает VS

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать для этих DLL отложенную загрузку (при которой DLL загружается не сразу, а только непосредственно перед первым вызовом функции из этой DLL) и тогда можно будет в начале программы задать путь поиска с помощью [SetDllDirectory](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setdlldirectoryw).

Подробнее об отложенной загрузке: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/build/reference/linker-support-for-delay-loaded-dlls

Answer (score -1):

Идём в свойства проекта -> каталоги Visual C++ -> дополнительные каталоги библиотек, добавляете ссылки на те dll которые хотите линковать с проектом, далее кладёте их в папку с .exe .

Comment: тебе по русски написали, что не запускается